# How to inspect boost::ptr_deque<std::string> in gdb?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, gdb

I have on ptr_deque (i.e. mydeque) of string and I want to inspect it with gdb.

I tried following thing,

```
pdequeue  mydeque void* 1
```

but it gives following errors.

```
Type boost::ptr_deque<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::heap_clone_allocator, std::allocator<void*> > has no component named _M_impl.
```

How to inspect boost::ptr_deque in gdb and iterate through all elements?

Answer (score 0):

The user-defined command you try to use, `pdequeue`, is intended to be used with `std::deque` containers. This is in fact documented in the `.gdbinit` you are using - I suggest to never use dotfiles by other people without a clear understanding of what they do.

Comment: which gdbinit is that? Is there a secret gdbinit club?

Comment: It's [this one](https://gist.github.com/skyscribe/3978082) or a variation thereof.